# Python programming and the use of for loops

Tags: python

Am new to programming and I just started studying and practicing. I started with python and am at for loops now. I kinda coded something that’s getting confusing for me because I can’t seem to understand how the code arrived at that output. Can someone please explain it to me. Would be very grateful.
Here’s the code I did:

```
a = range(1,20) 
total = 0 
for i in a : 
    if i%3==0 or i%5==0 : 
        total new = total + i 
print (total new)
```

And the output was 18.

Comment: `total new`?? Your variables should **not** have any spaces in them!!

Comment: Because, 0 + 18 = 18. (Assuming `total new` is a typo you made here). Result variable holds only the value computed during the last iteration; all others are overridden.

Comment: Your total will always be 0. This means total new(which cant contain space) will end up to be total new = 0+18.

Comment: Thanks very much. Exactly the understanding I needed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a = range(1,20)
```

Your program is creating a range of numbers between 1 and 19 (ranges go to one less than the max number you specify) like `[1, 2, 3, 4, ..., 19]`

```
total = 0
```

Your program is initializing the variable `total` to equal 0

```
for i in a:
```

You start looping through the range you made earlier, the first iteration `i=1`, the next `i=2` and so on until `i=19`

```
if i % 3 == 0 or i % 5 == 0:
```

You are selecting only the data where the modulo of 5 or 3 is 0. For example:

```
3 % 3 == 0 (0 remainder)
4 % 3 == 1 (1 remainder)
```

Now altering your variable to a reasonable name (without spaces) **that will actually utilize the variable we initialized above**

```
total = total + i # alternatively written "total += i"
```

This says that every time the value `i` is evenly divisible by 3 or 5 we will add it to our total

```
print(total)
```

We show the final result after adding values. You incorrectly scripted your program to do this though so it only showed the largest value that was evenly divisible by 5 or 3 which is 18.

When scripted correctly:

```
a = range(1, 20)
total = 0
for i in a:
    if i % 3 == 0 or i % 5 == 0:
        total += i
print(total)
```

Outputs

> 78

Comment: Thanks very much. Grateful!